# Selenium - Java - Actions Class - Click not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

When I use the following code for click or double click using Actions class, it seems like mouse click triggers but is not released. Apparently, the button is highlighted, but click doesn't perform completely.

Click Code:

```
WebElement refreshPreviewButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_previewInTabBtn']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
// Approach 1
action.click(refreshPreviewButton).build().perform();

// Approach 2
action.movetoElement(refreshPreviewButton).click().build().perform();
```

Double Click Code:

```
WebElement refreshPreviewButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_previewInTabBtn']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

// Approach 1
action.doubleClick(refreshPreviewButton).build().perform();

// Approach 2
action.movetoElement(refreshPreviewButton).doubleClick().build().perform();
```

Working code of other element on the same page:

```
WebElement previewInTabButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_previewInTabBtn']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(previewInTabButton);
action.perform();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="c3_axnPrvCHR2 c3_rows_nowrap c3_align_center c3_hidden" data-dojo-attach-point="_r2Cont">
   <div class="c3_axnPrvCBtns c3_axnPrvCBtnsL c3_rows_nowrap c3_align_center btn-sgmt-grp btn-group c3_br4 c3_bdr" data-dojo-attach-point="_btnsCont1">
      <div class="btn-sgmt c3_btn btn-icn-sq btn-icn-sq-34" title="preview" data-dojo-attach-point="_previewBtn">
         <svg class="c3i c3i_txt">
            <use class="c3i_u" xlink:href="#zi-eye-inactive"></use>
         </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="c3_bdr_r"></div>
      <div class="btn-sgmt c3_btn btn-icn-sq btn-icn-sq-34" title="code" data-dojo-attach-point="_codeBtn">
         <svg class="c3i c3i_txt">
            <use class="c3i_u" xlink:href="#zi-code"></use>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="c3_axnPrvCBtns c3_axnPrvCBtnsR c3_rows_nowrap c3_align_center c3_gpC16" data-dojo-attach-point="_btnsCont2">
      <div class="btn-default-outline2_new btn-sm c3_btn btn-fx" data-dojo-attach-point="_previewInTabBtn">
         <svg class="c3i c3i_txt">
            <use class="c3i_u" xlink:href="#zi-launch"></use>
         </svg>
         <div>Preview in tab</div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-default-outline2_new btn-sm c3_btn btn-fx" data-dojo-attach-point="_refreshPreviewBtn">
         <div>Preview</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edit 1: Added HTML

Edit 2: Added working code of other element on same page

Comment: I faced similar issues. In order to help here we need to see the page you working on (the link) and the Selenium code before the block you shared.

Comment: Hi @Prophet ! I'm using Page Object Model. The code block I shared is the only code in my method. I've added HTML. I'm sorry I can't attach screenshot of the page.

Comment: The HTML will not help here. We need to perform actual debugging

Comment: Could you please share what was the reason when you faced this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I remember. Maybe element should be scrolled into the view, add pause and only when the page is stable make this click/double click. By may be more reasons for that. Let me know if that helped

Comment: @Prophet - I'm able to perform double click on 'PreviewInTab' button which is next to 'RefreshButton'. But the same code doesn't work for 'RefreshButton'. Hope this helps in debugging.

Comment: No. Debugging is real running code via the IDE with ability to set break points etc. What we doing now is discussing, not debugging :)

Comment: Thank you Prophet for the input.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I could not help more without actual debugging.

Comment: It's fine. I learnt a new approach. :)

Comment: Hi @Prophet ! Adding wait before performing action solved the issue. :)

Comment: But previously you mentioned that this doesn't help?

Comment: I didn't use wait in the code previously. When I tried with wait for visibility, that too failed.

Comment: That makes sense :) I added an answer with more clear explanations. I hope this may be useful. Including the future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case clicking web element with `Actions` click or double click seems like the element was clicked / touched but the click / double click did not actually performed we can add a sleep like `Thread.sleep(2000);` before applying the `Actions` click.
Waiting for element clickability or visibility may not be enough here since `Actions` click works not exactly as Selenium click works. So `Actions` click may need the element to be in the visible viewport and clickable and also the page should be is a stable state, not during scrolling or rendering process.
So, generally I'd suggest to apply here to actions: wait for element clickability + additional sleep, like the following:

```java
WebElement useContentButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@data-dojo-attach-point='_previewInTabBtn']")));
Thread.sleep(2000);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(useContentButton).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having a similar issue:

I had to add wait before performing action.

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.doubleClick(useContentButton).build().perform();
```

I got this trick from [hover over each stars and then finally click on 4th star](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68759057/hover-over-each-stars-and-then-finally-click-on-4th-star).